# Binding for ListboxItems not updated

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

I have a Listbox with data-binding to payments of a project. When I add a new payment, the payment will be added to the list. The add-page is also used to edit the payments. The event is called, in debug-mode I can see the changed value of my payment, but the ListBoxItem is not going to be updated. At the end of the add-page an event will be called, which updates the listbox items:

```
GlobalNotifier.OnPaymentAdded();
```

The OnPaymentAdded calls a method which only notifies about the property changes:

```
OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Project");
```

The code of the listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="ListPayments" ItemsSource="{Binding Project.Payments}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="10,5,10,0">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Why are new items added, but existing items not updated? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that although the `Project`-object is updated, the `Payments` object (presumably a `List`) is not.

What you *could* try is the following:

1. Whenever the `List`-object is being manipulated (edited, items removed / added), fire the `PropertyChanged`-event for `Projects`
2. You can also switch the `List<Project>` to an `ObservableCollection<Project>`, which surely will fix your problem
3. If switching to `ObservableCollection` is out of the question for you, implement an override for the `OnNavigatedTo()` in the view that shows the list, and call the `PropertyChanged`-events (Project, Payments etc) from there.

Either one of these should fix your problem - it's all a matter of taste and preferences.

Comment: Payments was of type ICollection. Switching Payments to ObservableCollection solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your item properties are not dependency properties, or nobody fires propertychanged for them.

Comment: I have a break-point on the OnNotifyPropertyChanged and it's called on add and edit. but the items are not updated. I also tried to use an own propery _Payment_ as ItemsSource which points to Project.Payments, but nothing changed. What do you mean with _dependency properties_?

Comment: A dependency property is a property that is dependent on other variables - or the object in general. There is a lot of good articles on these properties out there, Google will be your friend on this one.

Comment: Could you post the source of your item class?